# onmouseout reset CSS with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onmouseover

I'm using JQuery to change the CSS style onmouseover, but I'm having difficult to reset on mouseout the CSS that I've changed onmouseover. What I'd like to do is:

Original style:
- Images of btn2 and btn3: grayscale

Onmouseover "btn1":
- Background of "btn1", "btn2" and "btn3" change to red 
- Images of "btn2" and "btn3": color

Onmouseout: original style

Onmouseover "btn2":
- Background of "btn1" and "btn2" change to red
- Image of "btn2": color

Onmouseout: original style

Onmouseover "btn3":
- Background of "btn1" and "btn3" change to red
- Image of "btn3": color

Onmouseout: original style

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn1').hover(function() {
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('color', 'white');
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('filter', 'grayscale(0%)');
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('-webkit-filter', 'grayscale(0%)');
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('filter', 'none');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('background-color', '');
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('color', '#b2b2b2');
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('filter', 'grayscale(100%)');
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('-webkit-filter', 'grayscale(100%)');
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('filter', 'gray'); 
    $('#btn2, #btn3').css('-webkit-transition', 'all .2s ease');
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#btn2, #btn3').hover(function() {
    $('#btn1').css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#btn1').css('color', 'white');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('#btn1').css('background-color', '');
    $('#btn1').css('color', '#b2b2b2');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #b2b2b2;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease; 
    margin: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
 background: red;
   color: white;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}

  .btn1 {
  padding: 0.5em 1.0em;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn1:hover {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1" class="btn1">social media</button>

<button id="btn2" class="btn"><img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137253/isolated/preview/90dd9f12fdd1eefb8c8976903944c026--cone-do--cone-do-facebook-by-vexels.png" width="80%"/></button>

<button id="btn3" class="btn"><img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137419/isolated/preview/b1a3fab214230557053ed1c4bf17b46c-logotipo-do--cone-do-twitter-by-vexels.png" width="80%"/></button>
```

Comment: Why not just add and remove classes?

Answer (score -1):

I solved using Add and Remove class!

```js
$("#btn1").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("btn12");
    $('#btn2, #btn3').addClass("btn12");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("btn12");
    $('#btn2, #btn3').removeClass("btn12");
  }
);

$("#btn2, #btn3").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("btn12");
    $('#btn1').addClass("btn12");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("btn12");
    $('#btn1').removeClass("btn12");
  }
);
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #b2b2b2;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease; 
    margin: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
 background: red;
   color: white;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}

  .btn1 {
  padding: 0.5em 1.0em;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn1:hover {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}

.btn12 {
 background: red;
   color: white;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1" class="btn1">social media</button>

<button id="btn2" class="btn"><img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137253/isolated/preview/90dd9f12fdd1eefb8c8976903944c026--cone-do--cone-do-facebook-by-vexels.png" width="80%"/></button>

<button id="btn3" class="btn"><img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137419/isolated/preview/b1a3fab214230557053ed1c4bf17b46c-logotipo-do--cone-do-twitter-by-vexels.png" width="80%"/></button>
```